# Using AWS Batch can a docker image be specified dynamically in a job definition?

Tags: aws-batch

I want to create jobs in AWS Batch that vary on the image that is used to launch the container. I'd like to do this without creating a different Job Definition for each image. Is it possible to parameterize the image property using [job definition parameters](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/batch/latest/userguide/job_definition_parameters.html#parameters)? If not, what's the best way to achieve this or do I have to just create job definitions on the fly in my application?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would really love this functionality as well. Sadly, it appears the current answer is no.
Batch allows `parameters`, but they're only for the `command`.

[AWS Batch Parameters](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/batch/latest/userguide/job_definition_parameters.html#parameters)

You may be able to find a workaround be using a `:latest` tag, but then you're buying a ticket to `:latest` hell.

My current solution is to use my CI pipeline to update all `dev` job definitions using the aws cli (`describe-job-definitions` then `register-job-definition)` on each tagged commit.

To keep my infrastructure-as-code consistent, I've moved the version for batch job definitions into an environment variable that I retrieve before running any terraform commands.

Comment: Do you have any specific commands on how you update your job definitions?

Answer (score -5):

Typically you make a job definition for a docker image.
However that job definition and docker can certainly do anything you've programmed it to do so it can be multi-purpose and you pass in whatever parameter or command line you would like to execute.

You can override most of the parameters in a Job definition when you submit the job.

Comment: Please provide a snippet if you've been able to override the job definition's `Image` property dynamically